# How Can I detect video or image from URL and display it accordingly in a single tag using React and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, material-ui

Ok Let me explain my situation, I am trying to build a Cover section for a profile page, where users can set either an image or a video as their cover.

I am unsure how to render both a video file and an image file based on the provided file URL.

I tried to find a similar project, but I found none.

Can you guys help me with how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do if just use Vide tag and put the same url in poster and src

```html
<video width="100px" poster="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/05/11/16/logo-2582748_1280.png" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/05/11/16/logo-2582748_1280.png" muted autoplay loop ></video>

<video
width="100px" poster="https://clashdome.io/images/newHome/video_home.mp4" muted autoplay>
  <source src="https://clashdome.io/images/newHome/video_home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

so if its a video then it will run as a video if its a image then it will render as image, also idk if its correct according to accessibility but its pretty clean and does the job perfectly